# Getting the error "ERROR: array subscript out of range" when multiplying matrices PL/pgSQL?

Tags: algorithm, matrix, multidimensional-array, plpgsql, matrix-multiplication

I'm traiying to code, as exercise, a PL/pgSQL function that multiplies two matrices then print the solution when called. I'm new in this language and can't find what's wrong with the code. Help!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION multiplicarMatrizes(matriz1 float[][], matriz2 float[][], OUT produto float[][]) AS
$$
DECLARE
    i integer;
    j integer;
    k integer;
BEGIN
    
    IF array_length(matriz1, 1) <> array_length(matriz2, 2) THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'O número de linhas da matriz 1 deve ser igual ao número de colunas da matriz 2';
    END IF;

    FOR i IN 1..array_length(matriz1, 1) LOOP
        FOR j IN 1..array_length(matriz2, 2) LOOP
            FOR k IN 1..array_length(matriz1, 1) LOOP
                produto[i][j] = produto[i][j] + matriz1[i][k] * matriz2[k][j];
            END LOOP;
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;

END;
$$ language plpgsql;


SELECT multiplicarMatrizes('{{1.0,2.0}, {2.0,1.0}}', '{{1.0,0.0},{0.0,1.0}}'); // CALLING THE FUNCTION
```

As result, I'm getting the error:

```
[44:1] Failed in 0 s.
[Exception, Error code 0, SQLState 2202E] ERROR: array subscript out of range
  Onde: função PL/pgSQL multiplicarmatrizes(double precision[],double precision[]) linha 15 em atribuição
  Line 44, column 1
```

Can anyone help, please?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL doesn't supports resize of multidimensional array when you modify one valule. Initially `produto` is empty array, so any change of this output variable should to fail. You need to initialize space of array by function `array_fill`

More - default value of any variable is `NULL`, and `NULL` + anything is `NULL` again.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION multiplicarMatrizes(matriz1 float[][],
                                               matriz2 float[][],
                                               OUT produto float[][]) AS
$$
DECLARE
    i integer;
    j integer;
    k integer;
BEGIN
    
    IF array_length(matriz1, 1) <> array_length(matriz2, 2) THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'O número de linhas da matriz 1 deve ser igual ao número de colunas da matriz 2';
    END IF;

    produto := array_fill(0, ARRAY[array_length(matriz1, 1), array_length(matriz2, 2)]);

    FOR i IN 1..array_length(matriz1, 1)
    LOOP
        FOR j IN 1..array_length(matriz2, 2)
        LOOP
            FOR k IN 1..array_length(matriz1, 1)
            LOOP
                produto[i][j] := produto[i][j] + matriz1[i][k] * matriz2[k][j];
            END LOOP;
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
END;
$$ language plpgsql;
```